# AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'NMSBoxesRotated'

Tags: python, opencv

I have a pretty straightforward [code](https://ideone.com/prnG9M) for text detection in python. But it is throwing an error (line 137) on running from command line.

cv.dnn.NMSBoxes works fine but it fails to recognise cv.dnn.NMSBoxesRotated.

Here is the error:

```
indices = cv.dnn.NMSBoxesRotated(boxes, confidences, onfThreshold, nmsThreshold)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'NMSBoxesRotated'
```

If anyone could point out what I'm missing, I'll be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install opencv-python --upgrade` to get the latest OpenCV? I had to do this as my existing installation also did not have `NMSBoxesRotated`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Yeah, it shows "Requirement already up-to-date: opencv-python (4.0.0.21)

Comment: Well that's weird. I have the exact cv2 version (4.0.0.21) and this one has `cv2.dnn.NMSBoxesRotated`. Can you try a `pip uninstall` followed by a reinstall?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code in the same environment that you're `pip install`ing into? Inside the code that is throwing the error, try printing `cv2.__version__`. Looks like `NMSBoxesRotated` was added in OpenCV 3.4.3, so anything older than that will not have it.

Comment: Also, *please* don't link code off-site. It is likely to die off when hosted elsewhere at some point, rendering it useless if others stumble upon it in the future. Of course, in your example it's not at all necessary to look at, but in that case, that should mean it isn't needed to link it at all. Just produce the minimum amount of code necessary to get your issue. For e.g. just `import cv2`, define some things to send into `NMSBoxesRotated`, and call it.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds it seems what you suggested was actually the problem. It shows OpenCV version to be 3.4.2 inside my code. Also I will keep the second comment in mind from now on.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Hi, I have installed opencv 3.4.2 by following the steps in this tutorial https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/ . Now I want to update to opencv 4 or the latest stable version. How should I approach it?

Comment: @OnePunchMan If you want to build from source, you'll have to follow those same directions again but checkout the latest version of OpenCV, there is no updater program/script for it. If your goal is just to write some basic OpenCV stuff with Python, you can just `pip install opencv-python`. But if performance is critical or this is going on an embedded device or you don't only want Python support, the best thing to do is build from source, like that tutorial shows.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install --user  opencv-python --upgrade
```

This command works for me, Thanks @JustinEzequiel

My OpenCV version is :

```
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.1'
```

This error is gone when I upgrade my opencv to 4.1.1